# Cell positioning like using flexbox but in CSS2?

Tags: css

So, apparently my pdf generation service only support CSS2 so my flexbox supported page looks like crap and I need help how to fix this.

I have a div container with a set height. I need to place out X amount of cells in this container (each cell containing an image and a text below). I say X because there won't be a fixed number but perhaps 1 -> 15 at max.

The cells should have a min width so that for example when there is a sixth cell, it should wrap so there are 5 cells in upper "row", then the sixth should be on its own row. If possible it would be good if the cells can be centered. I also need the height of the cells to be as big as possible while still maintaining inside the container. So say row-max is 5, at 6 cells, each cell should have height of 50% of parent height (2 rows). At 11 cells, they should have height of 33% etc

Is the best way to achieve this using a ul/li list? I tried using a table but since I can't set height on TD element, it didn't work at all. I have been stuck with this for days now with minimal progress. Any advice is really appreciated!

Comment: This sounds a better approach for javascript I think. Because you don't know exactly how many cells you have and you have to put a certain height depending on the number of cells.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want with just css. but with a little bit of jquery it's not difficult to achieve.

Basically you make your cells float with 20% width (so 5 per row) and height 100% (of the container), then you can change this height if the parent has more than 5 children (cells).

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
       <img src="" alt=""/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.cell {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:aqua;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.cell img {
    display:inline-block;
    height:75%;
}
.cell p {
    margin:0;
}
.new-height {
    height:50%;
}
```

where `.newheight`is the class I will add with jquery to "cell" if `container` has more than 5 children:

```
if ( $('.container').children().length > 5 ) {
     $('.cell').addClass("new-height"); 
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/pnktpkkf/)** (with 5 cells)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/dx20bt1r/1/)** (with 7 cells)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with Javascript:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>    <!--The div with the cells-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createTable(x){    //x is the number of cells
        var content = "";
        if(x <= 5){
            content = "<table height='100%'><tr height='100%'>";
            for(i = 1; i <= x; i++){
                content = content + "<td><img src='img" + i + ".png'/><br/>Text</td>";
            }
        }
        else if(x <= 10){
            content = "<table height='100%'><tr height='50%'>";
            for(i = 1; i <= x; i++){
                if(i == 6){content = content + "</tr><tr height='50%'>"}
                content = content + "<td><img src='img" + i + ".png'/><br/>Text</td>";
            }
        }
        else{
            content = "<table height='100%'><tr height='33%'>";
            for(i = 1; i <= x; i++){
                if(i == 6 || i == 11){content = content + "</tr><tr height='33%'>"}
                content = content + "<td><img src='img" + i + ".png'/><br/>Text</td>";
            }
        }
        myDiv.innerHTML = content + "</tr></table>";
    }
</script>
```